# can i add excel files to a html only based system ?

Tags: html

So yeah im currently working on a html based system.
i can only use html said my supervisor, just to make things easy and simple.

**My question : Can i add excel files to my html based system and if so , is it possible to work, save and edit the excel file.** Its hard to find answers on google that's why i'm asking here maybe someone will know...

I feel like its not possible with only html, but yeah like i said i'm only allowed to use html so said "my supervisor"

Greetings Drizzehh 
Sorry for my bad English i'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello As per me It is not possible only with Html .
Html is only Used for Displaying Valuesor Contents (Static only).

If you want to do some Dyanamic functionality Like CRUD operations then you should Use Script (javascript,v.b script) to perform such functionality